# Event not fired correctly in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium

So I have a view that contains some other views, that are all added using a loop.
The problem is I want to bind different events for each of those views and, for some reason, it seems that only the last event is being added to all the views (or even better, its overriding the previous events).

The code is actually pretty simple, I just don't understand why my variable "params" is always the letter "S" when I debug on the "card" controller:

```
    var stores = ["B", "O", "E", "K", "S", "F"];
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
{
    var view_b = Titanium.UI.createView
    ({
       backgroundColor:'#92b723',
       top:0,
       height:200,
       width:200,
       borderRadius: 30
       // layout:'horizontal'
    });

    // Handle event
    var params = stores[i];   
    view_b.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            var controller = Alloy.createController("card", params).getView();
            controller.open();          
    });

    $.carouselView.add(view_b);

        ... (some other stuff)
  }
```

What should happen is whenever I click on any view, it takes me to the card view and displays which letter I clicked. The way the code is right now I get an "S" by clicking in any view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic case of JavaScript scope confusion. What is happening is that the for-loop scope that the event listener is referencing is changing, so your `i` for each event listener is always 5 since it is the last scope created, therefore you always get "S" for every event listener.

First, it is not good practice to create event listeners in for-loops (mainly because of this scoping / context stuff), try this, separate your function into a named function, and then pass the params value with your view. That way you explicitly define which scope thee value belongs to (the views) instead of letting JavaScript do a number on you:

```
var stores = ["B", "O", "E", "K", "S", "F"];

// 1 - Name your event listener function
// This is a good idea anyway so that you can remove the listener later
function listener(e) {
    var controller = Alloy.createController("card", e.source.params).getView();
    controller.open();
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var view_b = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : '#92b723',
        top : 0,
        height : 200,
        width : 200,
        borderRadius : 30,
        // Pass your parameter with the view itself, more explicit
        params : stores[i]
    });

    view_b.addEventListener('click', listener);

    $.carouselView.add(view_b);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, works. Thank you. I'll edit your code to correctly access  the variable params.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your event listener from the loop, and wrap it in a function outside your loop. Something like:

```
function listenerHelper(view, params) {
 view.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  var controller = Alloy.createController("card", params).getView();
  controller.open();
 }
}
```

Then you call that function in the loop, and pass it the correct arguments.

Comment: While it is good to separate this out in its own function. This will still have the same scoping problem.

Comment: Actually it's working in my code. Although in my case the helper function is defined as a prototype.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted Josiah since the trick to put the variable params in the view might not come very clear to any other user (for me that as actually necessary).